# How to obtain a file with the content of all include files explicitly included?

Tags: delphi, generics, include, containers, freepascal

George "Mirage" Bakhtadze, the author of [Cast II engine](http://www.casteng.com/), has wrote about [an include-based technique which can be used to create generic containers and algorithms](http://www.pascalgamedevelopment.com/showthread.php?13172-New-language-features-have-a-place-in-game-code&p=83617#post83617). The source is avaiable from the [repo at Github](https://github.com/casteng/base/tree/dev/template). For me, his include-based technique is very interesting and useful, because it can be used for older Delphi and it is compatible between Delphi and Free Pascal (and non-Windows OS ready).

It would be more useful for me if the `_GenVector` written in "`gen_coll_vector.inc`" has `Sorted` & `Duplicates` properties and related behaviors (behaving the same way as in `TStringList`).

However, it is less obvious for me to insert the code when there are many include directives (I wonder how George managed this in the first place). Therefore, I wonder whether it is possible to obtain a sample file with all include files explicitly included ? It might be more straightforward for me to start from there.

I mean that there is certain built-in pre-processor that works before the actual compiling and whether there is a way to keep these intermediate files ?

Comment: `"I wonder whether it is possible to obtain a sample file with all include files explicitly included ?"`. You don't want to make the explicit inclusion yourself and wonder whether someone else has done that. This does not seem to be a question that fits [`SO guidelines`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for an acceptable question.

Comment: @LURD Surprising and strange you perceive that way. What I asked is (1) it seems to me that there is certain built-in pre-processor that works before the actual compiling and (2) whether there is a way to keep these intermediate files ?

Comment: You might want to include this in your question. And my comment was a way to have clarification on that point.

Comment: @LURD Clarification made.

Comment: In the time since you asked the question you could have written a crude pre-processor. Since this is a learning exercise you could just do the pasting manually. You'd have it done in 2-3 minutes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Nice suggestion ! :D (Could you share your experience about how would George manage this work in the first place ? I mean, do you think that he also needs to convert between {$I} and fully-included every now and then ? )

Comment: " it is less obvious for me to insert the code when there are many include directives " - then don't. You use that technique to declare one custom-tailored class - then spend some unit to declare that class and NOTHING but that. Then just use that unit anywhere you would need that class. OTOH i still think that you better use generics in both Delphi and FPC. We used this way in our large D2006 project and had different kinds of hard to track errors, forcing as to do clean/rebuild rather than just hitting F9 and running the program. So.. you are warned. whenever possible, use true generics

Comment: @Arioch'The Thank you for your comments very much !

Comment: @XichenLi I expect he might have needed to do that. For debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi does not use a pre-processor. It is (and always has been, since Turbo Pascal days) a single-pass compiler. There is no intermediate step. When you `{$I}` to include files, they are inserted in place in memory during the compilation process. Therefore, there is no "intermediate file" that can be kept.

Comment: Thank you for the information ! Do you know whether Free Pascal holds "intermediate files" ?

Comment: Sorry, no. I don't use Free Pascal at all. Perhaps someone else here can provide that information.

Comment: Not sure if this of any interest:http://sourceforge.net/p/dpp32/wiki/Home/.  I haven't used it myself but ISTR that Mr Hausladen at one point (maybe still does) provided a Delphi pre-processor that provided, amongst other things, support for a String case statement in Delphi source.

Comment: @MartynA Thank you for your comments very much !

Comment: @MartynA When I tried Andy's `dpp32` with George's bundled-`test` for `gen_coll_vector.inc`, I got `"To many file recursions."` The command is `dpp32.exe GenTestU.pas -I..`